# Requires Plugin for Test

Tags: wordpress

Hey guys i am looking for an wordpress plugin in which two user can take part in a quiz the quiz questions be decided by the admin and two user can take part in this test and after that they can check the compatibility between two is this kind of plugin available in wordpress?

Comment: Stack Overflow is dedicated to programming-related questions, please make sure to read [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Try asking on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: [Wordpress Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) might even be better suited for the question

Comment: Yes,But you have to customize for you requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A powerful and beautiful quiz plugin for WordPress.

**Functions**

- Single Choice
- Multiple Choice
- "Sorting" Choice
- "Free" Choice
- "Matrix Sorting" Choice
- Cloze function

**Plugin Link:**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pro-quiz/

**Demo link :**

http://www.it-gecko.de/wp-pro-quiz-quiz-plugin-fuer-wordpress.html

Lot's of plugin there in plugin dir,Please check following url.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/quiz